# alternate way to set Build and run using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, testng, intellij-plugin

I am working with Java source code with TestNG and frequently see errors like no test found to run ***OR*** Test event were not received whenever I try to run test cases in IntelliJ IDEA.

Which I can fix with changing Build and run using IntelliJ IDEA from Gradle.

[image]

I am looking for alternative way using which can add this somewhere as configuration instead of going and changing this manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gradle-idea-ext-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin) to [set build and run actions](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki#delegating-runbuild-and-test-actions) right in the Gradle build script:

import static org.jetbrains.gradle.ext.ActionDelegationConfig.TestRunner.CHOOSE_PER_TEST

```
plugins {
  ...
  id "org.jetbrains.gradle.plugin.idea-ext" version "1.0"
  ...
}

idea.project.settings {
  delegateActions {
    delegateBuildRunToGradle = true // Delegate Run/Build to Gradle
    testRunner = CHOOSE_PER_TEST    // Test execution: PLATFORM, GRADLE or CHOOSE_PER_TEST
  }
}
```

But actually, the fact that it works with IDE runner, but does not work with Gradle runner may indicate problems. I would first check if it works from the command line Gradle - make sure you run the same test with it as from the IDE. If it works in terminal but does not work in IDE, I would report a bug at [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with reproducible sample.